# WebsiteSpark and BizSpark : Which one ? Requirements?

Tags: bizspark, websitespark

I am a kind of freelancer owning a company but i am the only one in there, someone might join up this winter. I was concerning about WebsiteSpark and BizSpark. If i am developping somehow personal website and web application, web products for potential buyers and websites for future clients (this winter) Which program best fit me ?

Also what are the exact requirements and condition ? It is obligated to develop a website for a client within a time frame ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ireland/archive/2010/03/13/spark-programs-bizspark-versus-websitespark.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

I'm leaving the below for archive purposes.

Website Spark has been [deprecated in 2013](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-shutters-its-websitespark-developer-program/) so right now there's only [BizSpark](https://bizspark.microsoft.com/).

**OLD ANSWER**

I think you need WebsiteSpark. It's intended for web developers and web designers.
Bizspark is for start-ups that focus on developing their own core product.
But read MS pages thoroughly anyway to get a grasp of what exactly do you need in order to comply with these programs:

- http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/Faqs.aspx#Startup-Question1
- http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/support.aspx?tab=ProgramDetails